# Does Quickfix answer pending heartbeat requests before closing FIX connection?

Tags: quickfix

Basically i randomly get "heartbeat timed out" messages on my acceptor, maybe once a day, whereas heartbeat is configured to 60s, but i can't figure why this is happening.

I do close and reopen my initiator quite a few times per day. Could that be a reason for those heartbeat timeouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heartbeat configuration defines how often the engine sends a heartbeat message not the time out for those messages, this is defined by TCP/IP. If you are connecting and disconnecting a lot are you making sure that you send a logout message before dropping connection rather than just cutting it off. The system detects disconnection using these heartbeat messages and so a timeout means that either latency has become so high that the packets are dropped or that there is no engine on the other side to connect to. If you are connecting and disconnecting a lot there is also a high probability that you will do so whilst there is a heartbeat message in the æther which will give a heartbeat timeout.